Error when using implementations with different constraints in C# dependency injection
I'm struggling to make something like this code work
e instance is ok, with Foo1 and Foo2
But it throws a TypeLoadException when trying to build instance of c and instance of d.
it should build it Foo1 without any problem in both classes, one contained in an IEnumerable, isn't it?
Or should I write the choosing mechanism when I add it to the ServiceCollection?
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sc = new ServiceCollection();
        sc.AddSingleton(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo1<>));
        sc.AddSingleton(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo2<>));
        sc.AddSingleton<C>();
        sc.AddSingleton<D>();
        sc.AddSingleton<E>();

        var sp = sc.BuildServiceProvider();

        var e = sp.GetRequiredService<E>();
        var c = sp.GetRequiredService<C>();
        var d = sp.GetRequiredService<D>();
        
    }
}

public class C
{
    public IFoo<Bar>[] Foos { get; }

    public C(IEnumerable<IFoo<Bar>> foos)
    {
        Foos = foos.ToArray();
    }
}

public class D
{
    public IFoo<Bar> Foo { get; }

    public D(IFoo<Bar> foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}

public class E
{
    public IFoo<BarEq>[] Foos { get; }

    public E(IEnumerable<IFoo<BarEq>> foos)
    {
        Foos = foos.ToArray();
    }
}

public class Bar(int I);

public record BarEq(int I);

public interface IFoo<T> { }

public sealed class Foo1<T> : IFoo<T> { }

public sealed class Foo2<T> : IFoo<T> where T : IEquatable<T> { }

The exception I get is

System.TypeLoadException: 'GenericArguments[0], 'Bar', on 'Foo2`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

Stack trace
en System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeType inst) en /_/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/RuntimeHandles.cs: línea 540
en System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation) en /_/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/RuntimeType.CoreCLR.cs: línea 3522

.csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.0.23.0</FileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


For me it works just fine..

I create a new .net 8 console application and your codes worked well in my side, may I know how to reproduce your error? https://i.sstatic.net/KPPyEOBG.png

Your question is missing the necessary details. Please include the full exception details of the TypeLoadException.

@Steven I added more info, It's so weird.

@TinyWang Image from VS2022

What you're likely seeing is a first-change exception. This happens because of limitations in the built-in DI Container.
It tries to find out whether it can create a Foo2<T> based on the IFoo<Bar> abstraction and does this by trying to call typeof(Foo2<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Bar)). When that call fails -and it does- the DI Container skip the creation of Foo2<T> as its part of the collection.
There's nothing you can do about this and this first-chance exception can be ignored; your application will continue to run.

OMG... I feel stupid now...
